# How to create a timer in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have a question that may be simple but i hav failed to get it solved
I want to create a timer in pyqt using `QTimeEdit` with default time starting at `00:00:00` and increasing every second. I've tried the following code but it stops after adding only one second.

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.time)
self.timer.start(1000)

def time(self):
    self.upTime.setTime(QtCore.QTime(00,00,00).addSecs())
```

Comment: Show your whole code.

Comment: if you use all the time `QtCore.QTime(00,00,00).addSecs()` then you can't get bigger value. You have to create `QtCore.QTime(00,00,00)` only once and increase it in `time()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it but I think you need

```
self.curr_time = QtCore.QTime(00,00,00)

self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.time)
self.timer.start(1000)

def time(self):
    self.curr_time = self.curr_time.addSecs()
    self.upTime.setTime(self.curr_time))
```

You have to create `QtCore.QTime(00,00,00)` only once and later increase its value in `time()`.

Now you always use `QtCore.QTime(00,00,00)` and increase this value.

Answer (score 7):

`{yout time}.addSecs(1)` does not change time, but returns the changed time. Your must be use `{yout time} = {yout time}.addSecs(1)`

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore


def timerEvent():
    global time
    time = time.addSecs(1)
    print(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))


app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
time = QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)

timer.timeout.connect(timerEvent)
timer.start(1000)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:08
00:00:09
00:00:10
00:00:11
00:00:12
```

#

Answer (score 2):

You just need to take the current time in the `QTimeEdit` and increase it by one second:

```
def time(self):
    self.upTime.setTime(self.upTime.time().addSecs(1))
```

And make sure the `QTimeEdit` is initialized properly whenever the up-time begins:

```
self.upTime.setTime(QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0))
self.upTime.setDisplayFormat('hh:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
import sys

from PySide import QtCore

def calculo():
    global time
    time = time.addSecs(1)
    print(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

timer0 = QtCore.QTimer()
time = QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)
timer0.setInterval(1000)
timer0.timeout.connect(calculo)
timer0.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```