# how to connect volume slider in it to work with it

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6, volume

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaMetaData

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QSlider

class Ui_MainWinpage(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWinpage):
        MainWinpage.setObjectName("MainWinpage")
        MainWinpage.resize(507, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWinpage)
        self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        #slider
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 160, 16))
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged[int].connect(self.changeValue)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.play_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.play_song.setObjectName("play_song")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.play_song, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pause_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pause_song.setObjectName("pause_song")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pause_song, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.stop_song = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop_song.setObjectName("stop_song")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stop_song, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.previous = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.previous.setObjectName("previous")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.previous, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.shuffle = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.shuffle.setObjectName("shuffle")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.shuffle, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.next, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        #for volume
        self.volumeSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximum(32767)
        self.volumeSlider.setPageStep(1024)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.volumeSlider, 4, 0, 1, 2)

        MainWinpage.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWinpage)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 507, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menufile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menufile.setObjectName("menufile")
        MainWinpage.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWinpage)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWinpage.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionopen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWinpage)
        self.actionopen.setObjectName("actionopen")
        self.menufile.addAction(self.actionopen)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menufile.menuAction())

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWinpage)

        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        #for Qtmultimedia
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.changeVolume)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWinpage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWinpage)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWinpage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWinpage.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWinpage", "MainWindow"))
        self.play_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "play"))
        self.pause_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "pause"))
        self.stop_song.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "stop"))
        self.previous.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "previous"))
        self.shuffle.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "shuffle"))
        self.next.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "next"))
        self.menufile.setTitle(_translate("MainWinpage", "file"))
        self.actionopen.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "open "))

        self.previous.setText(_translate("MainWinpage", "Browse"))
        self.previous.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_handler)
        self.play_song.clicked.connect(self.play_music)
        self.pause_song.clicked.connect(self.pause_music)
        self.stop_song.clicked.connect(self.stop_music)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        blocked = self.media_player.blockSignals(True)
        value = self.horizontalSlider.value()
        self.media_player.setPosition(value)
        self.media_player.blockSignals(blocked)

    def changeVolume(self, value):
        self.volume = value


    def pushButton_handler(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.open_dialog_box()

    #for opening that file which you want to open
    def open_dialog_box(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = str(filename[0])
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        print("path is ",path)
        self.globalpath = path
        print("global paths is ", self.globalpath)

    #for playing that file which we had choosen from
    def play_music(self):
        artist = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.AlbumArtist)
        title = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.Title)
        self.media_player.play()
        print("song name:",self.globalpath)
        print(f"Now playing: {title} by {artist}")

    #for pause that selected music
    def pause_music(self):
        self.media_player.pause()
        print("song is paused")

    #for stoping that music
    def stop_music(self):
        self.media_player.stop()
        print("song is stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWinpage = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWinpage()
    ui.setupUi(MainWinpage)
    MainWinpage.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please be more specific, explain exactly what you want to achieve, because it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `pygame.mixer` you could consider using `PyQt5.QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer`. This has the advantage that `QMediaPlayer` emits signals when the duration and/or current position of the song has changed which you can use to update the position and the maximum value of the slider. The metadata of the song (title, artist, etc.) can be accessed via `QMediaPlayer.metaData`, e.g.

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QMediaMetaData

class Ui_MainWinpage(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWinpage):
        ....
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.horizontalSlider.setValue)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        blocked = self.media_player.blockSignals(True)
        value = self.horizontalSlider.value()
        self.media_player.setPosition(value)
        self.media_player.blockSignals(blocked)

    def open_dialog_box(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        path = str(filename[0])
        self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        print("path is ",path)
        self.globalpath = path

    def play_music(self):
        artist = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.AlbumArtist)
        title = self.media_player.metaData(QMediaMetaData.Title)
        self.media_player.play()
        print(f"Now playing: {title} by {artist}")

    def pause_music(self):
        self.media_player.pause()
        print("song is paused")

    def stop_music(self):
        self.media_player.stop()
        print("song is stopped")
```

Comment: thankyou so much Heike i ll use media_player ...thankyou

Answer (score 0):

To have the slider show the real-time position of the song that's playing, use a

- PyQt timer as explained in e.g. [How to create a timer in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327545/how-to-create-a-timer-in-pyqt)
- [pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_pos) to get the current position of the song (approximately anyway)
- `setValue` (and likely `setRange` on the slider.

There doesn't seem to be an API to find out how long the PyGame mixer's currently playing song is, so that may prove an additional hurdle.